# VSCODEでインテリセンスのホバー、ツールチップが文字化けしてしまいます

Tags: vscode

VSCODEをインストールしてインテリセンスを日本語化しました。
UTF-8のソースコードでは問題ないのですが、シフトJISのソースコードではソースコード内の文字は正しく表示されるのですが、インテリセンスで関数などのコメントがツールチップ内で文字化けしてしまいます。
これを修正するにはどのようにしたら良いでしょうか？

Comment: すみません説明が足りませんでしたソースファイルはPerlです。
CやC++は問題ないのですがperlは化けていしまいます。
関数ジャンプはできるのでそれほど不便ではないのですが気になってはいるので直したいなと思っています。

Comment: Perl使ってないのでよくわからないけど, Perlの場合 IntelliSense表示は拡張か何かで行われてるのですか？(普通なら(全体の) files.encoding 指定で shiftjisに変更可能な気がするけど…)